# How do I convert a std::function wrapper into a variadic function?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, variadic-templates

I have this very nice wrapper, but I'd like it to accept any number of T, S, R, Q, ...

```
template<typename U, typename T, typename S>
boost::variant<U, std::string> RunSafeFn2(const std::function<U(const T&,const S&)>& f, const std::string& errMsg, const  T& a1, const  S& a2)
{
    try
    {
        return f(a1,a2);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return errMsg;
    }
}
```

I tried the below and have been googling about, but man the error messages are cryptic - is what I'm trying to do even possible?

```
template<typename U, class ... Ts>
boost::variant<U, std::string> RunSafeFnN(const std::function<U(Ts)>& f, const std::string& errMsg, Ts ... ts)
{
    try
    {
        return bind(f, ts...);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return errMsg;
    }
}
```

Comment: From Clang, I get `error: declaration type contains unexpanded parameter pack 'Ts'` with squiggles under the `Ts` in `function<U(Ts)>`. If I were to judge, I'd say that's fairly clear.

Comment: Sure, but what's it telling me to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want, as this simple program shows:

```
template <class ... Ts>
void foo(std::function<void(Ts...)> f, Ts && ... ts) {
    f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(int)> f = [] (int i) { std::cerr << "hello " << i; };
    foo(f, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is, that once `RunSafeFn2` is a template, you may as well also template the functor itself. There's very little benefit to type erasing the callable when you are already a template. So in practice, it just makes more sense to do:

```
template <class F, class ... Ts>
void foo(F f, Ts && ... ts) {
    f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

Which still allows the usage above, but also allows doing:

```
foo([] (int i) { std::cerr << "hello " << i; }, 5);
```

Which will also be more efficient since you completely avoid creating a `std::function` object. To handle the return type, since you're limited to C++11, you could do:

```
template <class F, class ... Ts>
auto foo(F f, Ts && ... ts) -> boost::variant<decltype(f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)), std::string> {
    try {
        return f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
    ...
}
```

Edit: let me add one final thought: In C++11 and on, where callables are so easy to create, a much simpler alternative to this is actually to take a callable and *no* arguments:

```
template <class F>
auto foo(F f) -> boost::variant<decltype(f()), std::string> {
    try {
        return f();
    }
    ...
}
```

That's because it's pretty easy to capture around the arguments that you need. For example, if I had written my original example that way, I could use it by doing:

```
int i = 5;
foo([&] () { std::cerr << "hello " << i; });
```

This has pros and cons especially perhaps when dealing with move only types, but if you want to minimize maintenance burden and your use cases are simple, this is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Well, bind is a total red herring. It's used to create one callable from another. But you don't want to create a callable, you just want to call it. std::forward isn't strictly necessary for calling a callable like this but it is the most correct way for various reasons.

Comment: Can you do anything nicer in C++14 for the return type? We're on MSVC 2015.2

Comment: Yeah your final thought is what I originally did, till people wanted the ability to write their own failure wrappers incorporating the arguments in the failure wrapper.

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion Well, see my update which simplifies things quite a bit in general. I'm actually not sure if there is an easy simplification in 14; I was thinking to just use auto but then I realized that's not very compatible with returning a variant.

Comment: It's a lot more elegant but they can do clever things if you pass the args, eg check return in light of args.

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion I'm not sure what you mean by check the return in light of args. If RunSafeFn2 is going to really do something with the args, then yes, you need to pass them in of course. But I'm not sure exactly what you would plan to do with a completely generic signature like that. Keep in mind that a lambda can mutate local variables that it captures so it is also extremely flexible and powerful, even with no arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156052/discussion-between-probablyastupidquestion-and-nir-friedman).